# Assign static IP to printer connected to RJ45

Tags: dhcp, printing, cups

My raspberry pi is used as a print server and everything works except one thing... my printer which is connected directly via ethernet cable is not always found by cups. However, each time I restart my server while my printer is on, it does find it.

I suspect a different address is assigned each time I restart the printer which is why cups doesn't find it (I might be wrong though). My questions are:

- How can I see the MAC address of the printer?
- How can I assign a static IP to this printer so cups will always find it?

I'm using Rasbian 8 (jessie).

Comment: do you have a dhcp server on the Pi ?

Comment: Yes...as I said, the printer works but sometimes cups doesn't find it...

Comment: You may find `dnsmasq` easier to setup as a dhcp server than dhcpd (use -p 0 to not do any dns). `arp -n` will show mac addresses,  if your printer connects.

Answer (score 4):

Your printer should have a panel where you can read and modify the ethernet values like IP and MAC address. If it doesn't have this panel you can see them scanning your network hosts using a network scanner like [nmap](https://nmap.org/)

If you are using `dhcpd` as DHCP server you can easily assign an static IP address to a host using:

```
host HOST_NAME {
    hardware ethernet MAC_ADDRESS;
    fixed-address IP_ADDRESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you be more explicit on how I configure dhcp and how I find the MAC address?

Comment: I can't now sorry, if nobody does it before me I will do it later. Although you have a lot of tutorials in the net. [DHCP server](http://www.noveldevices.co.uk/rp-dhcp-server) and [nmap](https://www.cyberciti.biz/networking/nmap-command-examples-tutorials/)